# Quest procedure convergence after random answers

Tags: methodology, experimental-psychology, psychophysics

I use Quest procedure to find threshold for stereo disparity changes of a stimuli. I use a C++ implementation derived from the one in Psychotoolbox and I wonder whether the behaviour I observe is expected.

As my experiment is 2AFC I have set the probability to 0.75. If I answer honestly the thresholds goes down, then oscilate and get stable.
However, if I answer completely randomly the threshold quickly gets to maximum value.

Both those things are maybe expected but what puzzles me is the standard deviation that the method returns along with the mean.
For normal run this goes down slowly and at some point reaches my limit where I consider the procedure to be converged and I terminate the experiment.

**However for random answers the standard deviation goes down very quickly and after 5 answers the Quest terminates.**

As I use standard deviation to decide about convergence/success of the procedure I would get false very high thresholds this way.
Is this an error in implementation or is the error in the way how I interpret the standard deviation?